# json-rpc via curl

Tags: json-rpc

I'am running Bitcoin-qt 0.8.6.1-beta on Qt 4.8.3 on windows 7 64.

below is my .conf content in %appdata%/bitcoin folder

```
rpcuser=bitcoinrpc
rpcpassword=ahything
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcallowip=192.168.*.*
rpcport=9332 
server=1
daemon=0
addnode=69.164.218.197
```

using curl 7.26.0 (i686-pc-mingw32), I run the following command:

```
curl --user 'bitcoinrpc' --data-binary '{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"curltext","method":"getinfo","params":[]}' -H 'content-type:text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332
```

the pc ask for host password.

I have tried the .conf password and also the PC password (which is the one I log into my PC)

I always get error 401 (unauthorized) result.

Can anyone advice me where did I went wrong or how do I know which password it refer to?

TIA

Regards,
KK Gian

Answer (score 22):

You can also make a request by explicitly mentioning the username and password in the URI:

`http://bitcoinrpc:anything@127.0.0.1:8332/`

Making your request to this address should be sufficient.

So, full command:

```
curl --data-binary '{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"curltext","method":"getblockchaininfo","params":[]}' -H 'content-type:text/plain;' http://bitcoinrpc:anything@127.0.0.1:8332/
```

Comment: Keep in mind however that Steven Roose's suggestion won't work if there's an "@" in the password. Also depending on the connection location, the URL may be visible. It is certainly less secure and not suitable for remote system access.

Answer (score 15):

I got it to work by adding the password to the --user value, separated with ":".
So the example becomes:

```
curl --user bitcoinrpc:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --data-binary '{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"curltext","method":"getinfo","params":[]}' -H 'content-type:text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332
```

Where "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" is the rpcpassword stored in the .conf file.

Comment: Have you tried ?  
curl --user bitcoinrpc --password xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --data-binary '{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"curltext","method":"getinfo","params":[]}' -H 'content-type:text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332

Comment: curl: option --password: is unknown

Comment: `getinfo` is deprecated.  Should now be `getnetworkinfo`, `getblockchaininfo` or `getwalletinfo`.