# Cannot connect Sparrow wallet to node using username and password

Tags: bitcoin-core, sparrow-wallet

I'm trying to connect my node to Sparrow wallet on two computers on the same network. As I understand it, I have to authenticate using username/password option on Sparrow. This is the same computer I have the node running on. I have the `bitcoin.conf` file set up with

```
server=1
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=pass
```

However when I test the connection, I get this error message on Sparrow

```
Could not connect:

User/pass authentication failed
```

I've checked many times and the user and password match, so I'm not sure what is the issue here.

If I don't use the authentication option, Sparrow connects to the node with no issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get when [using curl to test Bitcoin RPC](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/19665/13866)